# How to load data returned from API call directly into BigQuery without storing on GCS?

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-bigquery

I am trying to write python to:

1. collect josn or csv data from our vendors' APIs,
2. load the data into BigQuery

Q: Could I load the data directly into BigQuery without storing on GCS?

Thanks,

Edit:
*Client.load_table_from_dataframe* might be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ideas:

- Use BigQuery's [streaming API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery) to insert the rows into tables. Note that this has an associated cost.
- Use an INSERT statement where you pass the values to insert as  [query parameters](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/parameterized-queries). You would use a query of the form, where you pass `array_of_structs` as a query parameter of type `ARRAY<STRUCT<x INT64, y STRING, z BOOL>>` (the struct should have the appropriate row type that you want to use). Note that there is a maximum request size limit for calls to BigQuery, however, which is 10MB if I remember correctly.

Query:

```
INSERT dataset.table (x, y, z)
SELECT x, y, z
FROM UNNEST(@array_of_structs)
```

Comment: Thanks! I was able do it using Apps Script - 1) convert the data into Blob format 'application/octet-stream' 2) and create a load job to load the data directly. The most similar method seems to be load_table_from_dataframe?

Comment: Okay, great! Consider posting what you did as an answer to your question is case anyone else is looking for a similar solution.